# Zend framework 1.11 : access model in bootstrap

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to pass ACL settings from model directory to ACL plugin in bootstrap.

```
    public function _initPlugins()
        {

        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $frontController->registerPlugin(new Petra_Plugin_Layout_MultiLayout());
        $frontController->registerPlugin(new Petra_Plugin_Controller_AclCheck(new Auth_Model_Acl_Acl()));   

        }
```

but autoloader cannot find class Auth_Model_Acl_Acl in Auth module. Is there any way to initialize MVC structure in bootstrap? Or maybe there is a better method to store ACL settings?

EDIT - more informations:

Bootstrap:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

private $view;

public function _initProperties()
{
    $this->bootstrap("layout");
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $this->view = $layout->getView();
}


public function _initAutoload()
{
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoloader->registerNamespace("Petra_");

            // Added recently - not helping :(
    $moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => '',
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules'

            ));

    $test = new Auth_Model_Acl_Acl();
    return $moduleLoader;


}

public function _initPlugins()
{

    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $frontController->registerPlugin(new Petra_Plugin_Layout_MultiLayout());

}





}
```

application.ini:

```
enter code here

[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

resources.modules = ""
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Directory structure:

```
/Application
    /Config
        application.ini  
    /layouts
        default.phtml
    /modules
        /admin
            ...
        /auth
            /controllers
                ...
            /models
                /Acl
                    Acl.php
            /views
                ...
boostrtrap.php
```

Comment: Have you registered the Petra_Plugin path with the autoloader?

Comment: Plugin registration work fine, i get error form `new Auth_Model_Acl_Acl()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It largely depends upon where the `Auth_Model_Acl_Acl` class is stored.

If it resides on the include path, perhaps in `library/Auth/Model/Acl/Acl.php`, then you just need to register the namespace with the autoloader. In `configs/application.ini`, just add:

```
autoloadernamespaces[] = "Auth_"
```

If the class resides in a module called auth, so that it resides in the file `application/modules/auth/model/Acl/Acl.php`, then you just need to be sure that you have initiated the modules correctly, typically with the following in `configs/application.ini`:

```
 resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
 resources.modules[] =
```

This will fire up the module application resource plugin which in turn registers a [module-autololoader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html#zend.loader.autoloader-resource.module) which should map correctly for your Acl class.

However, if this class wants to reside someplace else - like at the application root or in another module - then you have to set up some other [resource autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html) mappings.

Comment: Class is in model Auth and when I'm creating object of Auth_Model_Acl_Acl in controller everything works fine. Modules also work without any problem. I moved modules config to bootstrap but this doesn't help.

Comment: In your `_initPlugins()` method, include a call to `$this->bootstrap('modules');` before you register your plugins. That should initiate the resource autoloader at the module level that you need for the `Auth_Model_Acl_Acl` class.

Answer (score 1):

You define a resources autoloader 'Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader' to find classes without a namespace and from the directory APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules'

The autoloader has an array of resources:

```
array(8) {
  ["Model_DbTable"]=>
  string(74) "/path/to/application/modules/models/DbTable"
  ["Model_Mapper"]=>
  string(74) "/path/to/application/modules/models/mappers"
  ["Form"]=>
  string(65) "/path/to/application/modules/forms"
  ["Model"]=>
  string(66) "/path/to/application/modules/models"
............
}
```

The resource autoloader find this class 'Auth_Model_Acl_Acl' as a resource of 'Auth' or 'Auth_Model' or 'Auth_Model_Acl' or Auth_Model_Acl_Acl'. These are not a valid resources. The autoloader will return false at line 177 class 'Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource'.

The following will auto load your model class:

```
        $moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
                    'namespace' => 'Auth',
                    'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/auth'
                ));
```

**A solution (Create your custom autoloader) :**
Add the following after the autoloader. You can change 'Petra_Autoloader' to any other class you want.

```
$autoloader->pushAutoloader(new Petra_Autoloader, '');
```

Create a class that implements Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Interface

```
class Petra_Autoloader implements Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Interface{

    public function autoload($class)
    {
        // your implementation to load the class

    }
}
```

Bootstrap.php

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap {

//............
    public function _initAutoload() {

        $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        $autoloader->registerNamespace("Petra_");

        $autoloader->pushAutoloader(new Petra_Autoloader, '');

        $test = new Auth_Model_Acl_Acl();
        return $moduleLoader;
    }
//..............
}
```

Hope this helps

**Update**

In your application.ini you have the  appnamespace = "Application". Auto loading a model class 'Default_Model_MockupsElementsTypes' from APPLICATION_PATH "/models' will fail, because the auto loader is looking for classes starting with 'Application'. Class name 'Application_Model_MockupsElementsTypes'.

In my test machine I have this and it worked fine:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap {

//............
    public function _initAutoload() {

        $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        $autoloader->registerNamespace("Petra_");

        $autoloader->pushAutoloader(new Petra_Autoloader, '');

        $test2 = new Application_Model_DbTable_Guestbook; // classes loaded with the autoloader
        $test = new Auth_Model_Acl_Acl();
        return $moduleLoader;
    }
//..............
}
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer but the problem is autoloader cannon find any model, not even models stored in `/models' directory without any subdirectory and not only in auth module but in every one of them. In every example I've seen on the internet it works fine, i downloaded few of them and i'm unable to find any differences in my bootstrap.

zend throws fatal error: Fatal error: Class 'Default_Model_MockupsElementsTypes' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\Mobile_Mockup\mobile_mockup_1_0\application\Bootstrap.php on line 21 (different class test)

Comment: @Adam I have added more details to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues with the Module support in Zend Framework.  Do you have a bootstrap for each of your modules?  It can be blank, for example:

```
<?php
class Auth_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {}
```

The file should be Application/modules/auth/Bootstrap.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this, make sure that you have already bootstrapped db and frontController

```
public function _initPlugins()
{
    $this->bootstrap('db');
    $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    $frontController = $this->getResource('frontController');

    $frontController->registerPlugin(new Petra_Plugin_Layout_MultiLayout());
    $frontController->registerPlugin(new Petra_Plugin_Controller_AclCheck(new Auth_Model_Acl_Acl()));   

}
```

EDIT:
ok, how I do this in my apps is from my INI file:

```
[production]
;   PHP SETTINGS
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
phpSettings.session.auto_start = 0

; SET UP DEFAULT RESOURCES
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/default/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/default/layouts/scripts"
resources.layout.layout = "layout"
resources.layout.viewSuffix = php
resources.layout.pluginClass = "Perinatal_Controller_Plugin_LayoutSwitcher"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/default/controllers"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.plugins.acl = "Perinatal_Controller_Plugin_Acl"
resources.frontController.plugins.themer = "Perinatal_Controller_Plugin_Themer"
resources.frontController.plugins.mail = "Perinatal_Controller_Plugin_Mail"
...
```

This is where i load up my themes layouts mail and acl settings

Answer (score 0):

In my project I made all models available with the line below in application.ini:

```
includePaths.models = APPLICATION_PATH "/models/DbTable"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a 3-part tutorial on my blog, which does exactly what you want, and you'll have an easy control over the resources on the website. Its stored in XML, and you just need to provide "where" to get the current user role information.

try reading them at:

http://wolfulus.wordpress.com/

Tell me what you think, and any suggestions are welcome too.